# python, codecs, file.writelines(), UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, regex, file-io, codec

Do not know how to resolve the `UnicodeDecodeError`:

I am not able to write text to file --> `UnicodeDecodeError` about character `â = '0xe2'`.

1)  `â = '0xe2'` character for sure does not exists in that string

2) `re.search` is not able to find `â` character in the string, which I am trying to write `file.writelines(string)`

3) there is defined `errors='replace'` in file opening, thus `file.writelines()` should not complain about character errors.

```
File=codecs.open(fname, 'w','utf-8', errors='replace')

lines=smart_str( lines, 'utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='replace' )
# lines is 'some webpage text after BeautifulSoup.prettify which does not contain letter â ='0xe2', which is converted with Django smart_str to string'

FileA.writelines(lines) #gives UnicodeDecodeError : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9637: ordinal not in range(128).

myre = re.compile(r'0xe2', re.UNICODE) # letter   â = '0xe2'
print re.search(myre, lines) #gives None
linessub=myre.sub('', lines)
print re.search(myre, linessub)  #gives None

FileA.writelines(lines) #gives UnicodeDecodeError : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9637: ordinal not in range(128).
```

Comment: If you want to test whether a string contains a substring, just do `'\xe2' in s` instead of this `re` stuff, which wouldn't work anyway because `'0xe2' != '\xe2'`.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `codecs.open` so your file object expects unicode strings, not byte strings.

The point in using this function is that you don't have to encode the strings yourself before writing them to the file. You write unicode strings and the file object will encode them internally.

It looks like the `smart_str` returns UTF-8 encoded strings (seeing that you pass the encoding name to it). If you pass that to the codec-aware file object, which expects unicode, it will first try to decode the byte strings back to unicode. Because it will not know the encoding of the passed in string, it will use `ascii`. And that's where the error comes from because the string isn't ascii, it's UTF-8:

```
UnicodeDecodeError : 'ascii' codec can't decode...
```

So, you want to skip the encoding stage done by `smart_str` and simply write unicode strings to the file, or, switch from `codecs.open()` to the normal `open()` which works with bytes and as such expects already encoded byte strings.

By the way, your test for existence of the 0xE2 character will not work. Firstly, you use `r'0xe2'` as the pattern which is simply a 4 character string, not a single 0xE2 character. Secondly, you don't need `re` for something simple as that. Just try this:

```
print '\xe2' in your_str
```

Comment: The question is how to resolve UnicodeDecodeError about  character â = '0xe2', appearing when i try to write text "lines" to file.

Comment: I mean this character for sure does not exists in the text. How such error arose and what i should do about it?

Comment: I need smart_str since i perform search on the string before writing to file, which is not shown here. AFter search i am getting these errors and i am not able to write string to any file, neither opened with simple open nor opened with codecs.open(...).